# Found a Div style online although can't figure out how to place text within the Div

Tags: html, css

I found a nice responsive rectangle Div online with these style attributes:

```
.flex-rectangle{
    margin-left:16%;
    margin-right:16%;
    max-width:728px; 
    width:100%; 
    max-height:90px; 
    height:auto;
    background: #999;
}
.flex-rectangle:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 25%;
}
```

Although I am looking to place text within the Div, with their own styles and links etc...

```
<div class="flex-rectangle" align="center">
    <a href=""><? echo $ad_catch_line; ?></a><br />
    <? echo $ad_line_1; ?>
</div>
```

Yet for some reason anything inside the Div seems to display underneath and not on top? Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a container inside your `.flex-rectangle`? something like `.flex-rectangle-container` with `position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%`, also adding `position: relative;` to `.flex-rectangle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put text in the div AND have the padding on the pdeudo-element. The padding is what drives the size of the div.

You'd need to absolutely position the text on top of the div.

```css
.flex-rectangle {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 728px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 90px;
  height: auto;
  background: #999;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-rectangle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 25%;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  /* not required - just for demo */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color:white;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-rectangle">
  <div class="inner">
    <a href="#1">Link</a>
    <span>Some Other text</span>
  </div>  
</div>
```